# get distinct records in sql

Tags: sql

I have written a following query to get customer emailaddress, ordercount that is how many orders the customer has placed, Totalprice of the order. But i am getting duplicated result.

I want to have distinct records like:

```
Customer A, 5 orders, $125 total
Customer B, 2 orders, $150 total
```

but i am getting the results like:

```
Customer A, 4 orders, $100 total
Customer A, 1 order, $25 total
Customer B, 1 order, $100 total
Customer B, 1 order, $50 total
```

Can you please help me how can i get the result as i want. I have written the following Query:

```
    Select 
    customers.CustomerID,
    customers.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Ordercount,
    Sum(OrderDetails.TotalPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalPrice 
from 
    customers 
    INNER JOIN Orders ON customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
GROUP BY 
    customers.CustomerID,
    customers.EmailAddress,
    Orders.OrderID,
    OrderDetails.TotalPrice,
    OrderDetails.Quantity 
ORDER BY customers.CustomerID, orders.OrderID desc
```

Comment: Why do you have customerID in your group by, but don't select it?

Comment: Sorry i posted wrong query my query ia as follows:Select customers.CustomerID,customers.EmailAddress,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Ordercount,Sum(OrderDetails.TotalPrice  * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalPrice from customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID GROUP BY customers.CustomerID,customers.EmailAddress,Orders.OrderID,OrderDetails.TotalPrice,OrderDetails.Quantity
ORDER BY customers.CustomerID, orders.OrderID desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to `group by` the fields which are in the select and not part of a `COUNT` or `SUM`

```
Select 
    customers.CustomerID,
    customers.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Ordercount,
    Sum(OrderDetails.TotalPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalPrice 
from 
    customers 
    INNER JOIN 
    Orders ON customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
    INNER JOIN 
    OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
GROUP BY 
    customers.CustomerID,
    customers.EmailAddress
ORDER BY 
    customers.CustomerID desc
```

Comment: but i am getting the following error: Column "Orders.OrderID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. if i do not include it.

Comment: ok just order by the customer id. or order by COUNT(Orders.OrderID) if you want the most orders at the top

Answer (score 1):

The problem is still on the `GROUP BY` part, try it like this:

```
Select customers.CustomerID,
       customers.EmailAddress,
       COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Ordercount,
       Sum(OrderDetails.TotalPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalPrice
from customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY customers.CustomerID,
         customers.EmailAddress
ORDER BY customers.CustomerID, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) desc
```

Comment: i posted the wrong query you can check above the correct query in the comment.

Comment: i get the following error : Column "Orders.OrderID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user818671 indeed, use what I put now.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping and ordering by columns such as Order ID is the problem - try:

```
Select customers.CustomerID,
       max(customers.EmailAddress) AS EmailAddress,
       COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Ordercount,
       Sum(OrderDetails.TotalPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalPrice
from customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY customers.CustomerID
ORDER BY customers.CustomerID
```